# How turn this monthly xarray dataset into an annual mean without resampling?

Tags: python, numpy, python-datetime, python-xarray

I have an xarray of monthly average surface temperatures read in from a server using `open_dataset` with `decode_times=False` because the calendar type is not understood by xarray.

After some manipulation, I am left with a dataset `my_dataset` of surface temperatures ('ts') and times ('T'):

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (T: 1800)
Coordinates:
  * T        (T) float32 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5 10.5 11.5 ...
Data variables:
    ts       (T) float64 246.6 247.9 250.7 260.1 271.9 281.1 283.3 280.5 ...
```

'T' has the following attributes:

```
Attributes:
    pointwidth:  1.0
    calendar:    360
    gridtype:    0
    units:       months since 0300-01-01
```

I would like to take this monthly data and calculate annual averages, but because the T coordinate aren't datetimes, I'm unable to use `xarray.Dataset.resample`. Right now, I am simply converting to a numpy array, but I would like a way to do this preserving the xarray dataset.

My current, rudimentary way:

```
temps = np.mean(np.array(my_dataset['ts']).reshape(-1,12),axis=1)
years = np.array(my_dataset['T'])/12
```

I appreciate any help, even if the best way is redefining the time coordinate to use resampling.

Edit:
Requested how xarray was created, it was done via the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr

filename = 'http://strega.ldeo.columbia.edu:81/CMIP5/.byScenario/.abrupt4xCO2/.atmos/.mon/.ts/ACCESS1-0/r1i1p1/.ts/dods'
ds = xr.open_dataset(filename,decode_times=False)

zonal_mean = ds.mean(dim='lon')
arctic_only = zonal.where(zonal['lat'] >= 60).dropna('lat')
weights = np.cos(np.deg2rad(arctic['lat']))/np.sum(np.cos(np.deg2rad(arctic['lat'])))
my_dataset = (arctic_only * weights).sum(dim='lat')
```

Comment: Have you tried using `decode_cf` as in [ts analysis](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html)

Comment: @sharatpc Thank you for this suggestion, but I am unable to use `decode_cf` without getting: `ValueError: units must be one of 'seconds', 'minutes', 'hours' or 'days' (or singular version of these), got 'months'` even after changing the calendar to 360_day

Comment: can you post how the dataset was created, rather than the output? makes it easy to reproduce.

Comment: @sharatpc edited to reflected creation of dataset

Comment: url or am guessing a Geo JSON is needed. at least first few coordinates to work with.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be blasting the url but I guess it's publicly available climate data...oh well the link is there now, have at it.

Comment: oh crap. memory error on my 8 gig: file too big to read. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common problem, especially with datasets from INGRID. The reason xarray can't decode the date whose units are "months since..." is due to the underlying netcdf4-python library's refusal to parse such dates. This is discussed in a [netcdf4-python github issue](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/issues/434)

> The problem with time units such as "months" is that they are not well defined. In contrast to days, hours, etc. the length of a month depends on the calendar used and even varies between different months.

INGRID unfortunately refuses to accept this fact and continues to use "months" as its default unit, despite the ambiguity. So right now there is this frustrating incompatibility between INGRID and xarray / python-netcdf4.

Anyway, here is a hack to accomplish what you want without leaving xarray

```
# create new coordinates for month and year
ds.coords['month'] = np.ceil(ds['T'] % 12).astype('int') 
ds.coords['year'] = (ds['T'] // 12).astype('int')
# calculate monthly climatology
ds_clim = ds.groupby('month').mean(dim='T')
# calculate annual mean
ds_am = ds.groupby('year').mean(dim='T')
```

Comment: @LonelyHeartsClub - did this work for you? If so, could you accept my answer?

Comment: I will try it now, I work on weekends so unfortunately I didn't get the chance to try it yet.

Comment: this worked beautifully. Thank you again for the help. I've accepted you answer.